# Parsing and iterating through an XML structure where each entry has multiple attributes

Tags: perl, hash, foreach, xml-parsing, key

I'm trying to deal with an XML list of items (in this case, images) and iterate over each one.  I don't really understand Perl or hashes, but I found a few explanations and examples (many here) and wrote something that seemed to work.  The XML is a list of  elements, each of which contains a unique 'id' attribute.

I'm using XMLin from XML::Simple to parse the XML.

When the list contains multiple  elements, it iterates through by 'id'.  But it seems that when there is only one, it gets confused, and treats each attribute of the  element as its own value, which results in a run-time error.

> Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

I'm guessing that the problem is that the hash key doesn't that 'id' is the unique key, at least when there's only one  entry.  So I added code to dump the keys.  I also added a line to print what the `$image` is in the `foreach` loop.  In the case that breaks, the line `print "In loop; image ID=$image\n";` displays `In loop; image ID=Serial`  Since `Serial` is an attribute at the same level as `id`, I'm guessing this is the problem (not properly using `id` as the key).

Here's my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use XML::Simple;

    my $album_data_file = $ARGV[0];
    my $album_file_list = $ARGV[1];
    my $do_dump_data    = $ARGV[2];

    my $album_data = XMLin ( $album_data_file );
    my $LIST_FILE;

    if ( defined $album_file_list && "$album_file_list" ne "" )
    {
        if ( open ( $LIST_FILE, ">", "$album_file_list" ) )
        {
            print "Opened file $album_file_list as $LIST_FILE\n";
        }
    }

    if ( defined $do_dump_data && $do_dump_data eq "true" )
    {
        use Data::Dumper;
        print "data:\n\n";
        print Dumper ( $album_data );
        print "\n\n\n\n";

        print "keys:\n\n";
        print Dumper ( keys %{$album_data->{Images}->{Image}} );
        print "\n\n\n\n";
    }

    foreach my $image ( keys %{$album_data->{Images}->{Image}} )
    {
        print "In loop; image ID=$image\n";

        my $ref = $album_data->{Images}->{Image}->{$image};

        #
        # Write to files list: file name, ID, key, size, MD5
        #
        print $LIST_FILE ( "$ref->{FileName}\t$image\t$ref->{Key}"
                 . "\t$ref->{Size}\t$ref->{MD5Sum}\n" );
    }

    close ( $LIST_FILE );
```

Here's a sample XML file that breaks it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <method>images.get</method>
  <Images>
    <Image id="123" Key="xyz" Type="Album" Caption="Room 5083" FileName="MVI_2838.AVI" Format="MP4" Height="480" Keywords="China; Suite" LastUpdated="2014-04-19 11:49:45" Position="1" Serial="0" Size="116033" Width="640" Date="2014-04-19 11:46:24" Hidden="0" MD5Sum="6151e20053eeda87c688f8becae0d402" Watermark="0">
      <Album id="345" Key="zzy" />
    </Image>
  </Images>
</rsp>
```

Here's the result of dumping the full $album_data:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'method' => 'images.get',
      'Images' => {
                  'Image' => {
                             'Serial' => '0',
                             'Format' => 'MP4',
                             'Keywords' => 'China; Suite',
                             'Type' => 'Album',
                             'Size' => '116033',
                             'MD5Sum' => '6151e20053eeda87c688f8becae0d402',
                             'id' => '123',
                             'Key' => 'xyz',
                             'LastUpdated' => '2014-04-19 11:49:45',
                             'Album' => {
                                        'id' => '345',
                                        'Key' => 'zzy'
                                      },
                             'Position' => '1',
                             'Height' => '480',
                             'Date' => '2014-04-19 11:46:24',
                             'Caption' => 'Room 5083',
                             'FileName' => 'MVI_2838.AVI',
                             'Hidden' => '0',
                             'Width' => '640',
                             'Watermark' => '0',
                           }
                },
      'stat' => 'ok'
    };
```

Here's the result of dumping the keys %{$album_data->{Images}->{Image}} construct:

```
$VAR1 = 'Serial';
$VAR2 = 'Format';
$VAR3 = 'Keywords';
$VAR5 = 'Type';
$VAR6 = 'Size';
$VAR7 = 'MD5Sum';
$VAR9 = 'id';
$VAR10 = 'Key';
$VAR11 = 'LastUpdated';
$VAR12 = 'Album';
$VAR14 = 'Position';
$VAR15 = 'Height';
$VAR16 = 'Date';
$VAR17 = 'Caption';
$VAR19 = 'FileName';
$VAR20 = 'Hidden';
$VAR23 = 'Width';
$VAR24 = 'Watermark';
$VAR27 = 'Duration';
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [`XML::Simple #Status of this Module`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSimple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE):

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) is highly recommended.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options and the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with unexpected results.
>
> Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new features are unlikely to be added.

`XML::Simple` is a useful module to quickly parse xml if you're familiar with perl complex data structures.  However, whenever the xml gets too complex, the module outlives it's usefulness because of it's arbitrary method of parsing certain structures depending on a lot of configuration variables.

I still use `XML::Simple` on rare occasions, but I'd advise you to look at either [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig) or the afforementioned `XML::LibXML` to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate **Miller**'s caution that `XML::Simple` is discouraged and his warning that it is difficult to use due to so many options which interact in ways that are hard to define and manage.  While looking into the replacement modules he suggested, I stumbled on some information that I should have been aware of prior to using `XML::Simple` in the first place.  In particular, the fact that my script worked when multiple images are in the XML but fails when there is only one points out that if one is using `XML::Simple`, it is often critical to set the `ForceArray` option to the element(s) that are always supposed to be in an array, even if a particular XML file only happens to contain one.  Otherwise, the element will sometimes be an array and sometimes a scalar, causing the exact run-time error I was seeing.

So, in my case, setting `forcearray => [ 'Image' ]` makes the code work (by forcing all `<image>` elements into an array, even if there is only one), at less immediate effort than trying to figure out how to use a different XML parsing module (although I have no doubt that making the effort to do so will save time in the future).